# Javascript: For an element clipped overflow, how do get its non-clipped top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

On the html page I'm looking at there's an image that's 500x500px that is in a container with overflow:hidden that is only 200 x 200px, so the image is overflowing. How do I get NOT the top of the image element, but the top of the part of the image element that is not overflowing (which would be the top of the container)?

I want to do this without cycling over the image element's parents, then checking their overflow style, and if they are overflow:hidden then comparing their bounding box with the img's bounding box to see if the image is overflowing, then getting the top of that ancestor element. Is there a more efficient way than that? Scrollheight and OffsetHeight/ClientHeight give the same values for this image element.

EXAMPLE, i want the top the "getMe" element, but the top of the part that is not overflowing the container (so the equivalent of the top of the container):

```html
<div style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:100px;width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden">
    <div id="getMe" style="background-color:blue;position:relative;top:-20px;left:-50px;width:200px;height:150px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a text-based [mcve] of the issue

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not clear what you mean with *"How do I get NOT the top of the image element, but the top of the part of the image element that is not overflowing"*

Comment: Yes, sorry. I want the top of the portion of the image element that is not overflowing, not he top of the image element as a whole (which would include the parts that are overflowing)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but wouldn't the "top" of the "non overflowing part of the image" always be the same as the top of the container element (if you refer to the distance from the top of the document) or 0 (if you refer to the distance from the top of the container element)?

Comment: @secan Normally yes, but if you inspect the inner `div` you can see it overflows on the top because of the `top:-20px`.

Comment: @Reyno but the top of _visible_ ("non overflowing") part of the image would still be 0 (in relation to the container) / parent.top (in relation to the page), wouldn't it?

Comment: @secan You are correct, the top of the 'non overflowing' part would be the container that has overflow:hidden! However, the container isn't always the parent, it could be an ancestor. I wanted a solution of finding this top that didn't require iterating over the elements ancestors and checking to see if they have overflow and if they clip the image. Was wondering if there was just a 'element.clippedHeight' attribute or something im missing, but it looks like there isn't

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get...

> ...a DOMRect object providing information about the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

If you use it on both the outer `div` and the inner one, and take the higher value for `top`, that's the position at which the top of the non-clipped part of the image is.

In your example, it's the outer `div`'s top:

```js
"use strict";

const inner = document.getElementById("getMe");
const parent = inner.parentElement;

const innerBounds = inner.getBoundingClientRect();
const parentBounds = parent.getBoundingClientRect();

const topOfVisiblePart = Math.max(innerBounds.top, parentBounds.top);
console.log(topOfVisiblePart); // 50 (or so)
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:100px;width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black">
    <div id="getMe" style="background-color:blue;position:relative;top:-20px;left:-50px;width:200px;height:150px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

...but if we make the nested `div` not clipped by the parent, it'll be the top of the nested `div`:

```js
"use strict";

const inner = document.getElementById("getMe");
const parent = inner.parentElement;

const innerBounds = inner.getBoundingClientRect();
const parentBounds = parent.getBoundingClientRect();

const topOfVisiblePart = Math.max(innerBounds.top, parentBounds.top);
console.log(topOfVisiblePart); // 50 (or so)
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:100px;width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black">
    <div id="getMe" style="background-color:blue;position:relative;top:10px;left:-50px;width:200px;height:150px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also use [`getClientRects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) to get more detailed information about the rectangles for the element, for elements (such as inline elements spanning lines) that may have multiple rectangles.

Comment: Thanks! That WOULD work however the element with overflow isn't always a parent, it can be an ancestor. I forgot to specify this. I was hoping there would be an answer like element.VisibileHeight lol, that would save me from having to iterate all of the elements ancestors to find the one with overflow.

Comment: @DanielGoldberg - :-) Hard to prove a negative, but I suspect there isn't, and you're going to be stuck with that loop. Still, it's not too bad...